# Dynamically remove and add strings in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a HTML5 project and I need to use localstorage.
I want to be able to dynamically remove items from my localstorage. This means that if I have five items, and I want to remove the second item, the third, fourth and fifth item will be automatically allocated to a lower place so that I don't have a gap left (as this is very annoying when I want to print my whole local storage).

Comment: Friend can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: localstorage is key-based my friend, not an array

Comment: Bad approach. As @AmineHajyoussef already said, localstorage is key-based.. it's totally wrong treating it like an array and it could cause you annoying problems. If I were you, i'd change approach..

Comment: @zzlalani we don't have anything right now, that's the problem. We've been looking for the past hour, but we have found nothing that works.
What we have so put something in our locatestorage (which is easy as pie) is localStorage.text = "first,second,third,fourth,fifth";
What we plan on doing is use a first string for the names and the second string for the description that belongs to that name. So the first description belongs to the first name etc... This should not be that hard to accomplish, but we just can't find how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 localStorage aka Web Storage, uses keys to store string values. So you can store objects or arrays by converting them to JSON before storing:

```
// define an array of objects
var arr = [
    { name : 'first', description : 'first description' },
    { name : 'second', description : 'second description' },
    { name : 'third', description : 'third description' }
];

// store the array to localStorage as a JSON string
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(arr));

// retrieve the JSON from localStorage and parse it back to an array
var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));

// remove the second object from the array
arr.splice(1, 1);

// let's update the first object too
arr[0].name = 'first name';

// save it back to localStorage
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what we need to start :) a good basic explanation. We'll keep you up to date.

Comment: Thank you for you help! This is exactly what we wanted. It works just the way we want it to. Will accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (localStorage.text) 
{ 
    var text1 = localStorage.text; 
    var splitText1 = text1.split(','); 
    if (splitText1.length > 0) 
    for (i in splitText1) 
    { 
        var div = document.createElement("div"); 
        div.setAttribute("id", "medicament"); 
        div.innerHTML = "<h1>" + splitText1[i] + "</h1>"; document.body.appendChild(div); 
    } 
}
```

This is the code we use to print things on our screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jstorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) to solve your problem.